# JQuery slideDown does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```
<div> 
   <div id="doit">press me</div>     
    </div>

    <div class="parts_wrapper" id="index1">
      <div class="parts"> 
       <div class="part">test1</div>
       <div class="part">test2</div>
       <div class="part">test3</div>
       <div class="part">test4</div>
       <div class="part">test5</div>
       <div class="part">test6</div>
       <div class="part">test7</div>
      </div>  
     </div>     


 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $("#doit").on('click', function() {
      $("#index1").slideDown("slow");
  });
 </script>
```

and here is the responding css:

```
.parts_wrapper{
    display:none; 
}
.parts{
    position:absolute;
    top:204px;
    left:54px;
}
.part{
    width: 120px;
    font-size:13px;
    background-color:#000;
    color: #FFF;
}
#doit{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

However, "parts_wrapper" does not slide as to appear, it just shows up! Do you have any idea why that happens?

Thank you very much

http://jsfiddle.net/bgqgjxzh/

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that .slideDown() is removing the `display:none` style when the animation is complete.

Comment: Why is every other answer downvoted when they all offer the same solution? Seems harsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with your `position:absolute`.
When you remove your wrapper it should work:

**HTML**

```
<div class="parts" id="index1"> 
   <div class="part">test1</div>
   <div class="part">test2</div>
   <div class="part">test3</div>
   <div class="part">test4</div>
   <div class="part">test5</div>
   <div class="part">test6</div>
   <div class="part">test7</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parts{
    position:absolute;
    top:204px;
    left:54px;
    display:none; 
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w0mnr6rj/)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the `position:absolute` from the `.parts`. Rest of your code looks perfect.

Updated CSS for parts:

```
.parts{
    top:204px;
    left:54px;
}
```

Working example:http://jsfiddle.net/bgqgjxzh/2/.

*Let me know if I helped you out :)*

Comment: so this will change the position of `parts` as `top` and `left` have no effect

Answer (score -1):

you only need to remove  `position:absolute;` from parts class like this

```
.parts{
    top:204px;
    left:54px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check this snippet

I have something similar to what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
#panel, #flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
  top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```